# What does this statement mean in C?((uint16_t)0x0001)

Tags: c

```
#define something ((uint16_t)0x0001)
```

does that mean hat something becomes uinit16_t with a value of 1
I am actually programming a MCU and this statement seems to allow me to change and control a single bit, however, i am not sure why it does not reset the other bits 15 bits as only the first bit is set.

Comment: This statement doesn't "reset" anything, it just defines a macro that expands to a number. How it affects other values depends on the expression it's used in.

Comment: When you use `something` in your code, it's just replaced by `((uint16_t)0x0001)` literaly. So it's equivalent to writing it directly, and hence it has nothing to do with reseting something. The value `0x0001` must have somethig to do, and if you want to reset all the bits I think it should then be `#define something ((uint16_t)0xFFFF)` since if `0x0001` is resetting the last bit then I suppose that binary `b1111111111111111` will reset the 16 bits.

Comment: You can set the least significant bit of a variable `var` using `var |= something;`.  Subject to some constraints, you can reset the least significant bit in `var` using `var &= ~something;`.  You can flip the least significant bit using `var ^= something;`; and you can find the value of the least significant bit using `var & something`.

Comment: Note that many embedded processors have alternate addresses for special function registers where writing a 1 sets (or for another address, clears) a bit in the main register  while writing a 0 has no affect.  So the original idea may be right, it is just hardware rather than the C language which accomplishes it.  This can make things like twiddling GPIOs both faster and more atomic than the read-modify-write otherwise needed to change a single bit in a register whose state is not already known.

Answer (score 2):

```
0x0001
```

is a value of `1` of type `int`

```
((uint16_t)0x0001)
```

is also a value of `1` but of type `uint16_t`

Comment: Note: I _was_ going to comment that `0x0001` was `unsigned` - but this is correct: `int`.  2 nice answers - the long and short of it.

Answer (score 2):

That's not a statement. It's a preprocessor directive, specifically a macro definition.

```
#define something ((uint16_t)0x0001)
```

This does nothing by itself. It means that if the word `something` appears later in the program, it will be replaced by the token sequence `((uint16_t)0x0001)`.

`0x00001` is just another way of writing `1`. It's a constant of type `int`, with the value `1`. (The `0x` prefix means it's hexadecimal rather than decimal.)

`uint16_t` is a *typedef*, defined in the standard header `<stdint.h>`. It's a 16-bit unsigned integer type.

`(uint16_t)` is a *cast operator*. It specifies a conversion of its operand to the specified type.

Putting that all together, the expression `((uint16_t)0x0001)` is a constant expression of type `uint16_t` with the value `1`. And given the macro definition, any occurrence of `something` is replaced by that expression.

So it's just a number of a specific type. By itself, it's not going to let you "change and control a single bit", but you might be able to use it for that purpose if you use it properly.

I hope the actual macro has a more meaningful name than `something`. if you had shown us how it's used (perhaps as a bit mask?), we might have been able to provide more information.

Comment: Can you please explain bit masking in a MCU perspective.

Comment: What don't you understand?